# How can I set an object to an empty object in Python?

Tags: python, variables, object

This may be a dumb question but it has been awhile since I have worked with python...

So, I have a set of objects, for example:

```
p1 = Person("Name", "Age")
p2 = Person("Name", "Age")
..
```

How can I, essentially, copy one object and put it in an empty object?

Comment: Take a look at copy: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: What's an empty object? You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1):

'Empty' objects don't really exist but for demonstration purposes let's say `empty is None`.

Onwards, you can 'copy' them and you can do it two different ways:

- Via the assignment statement where the names of the "copied" objects *all reference the same object*
- Via `copy.deepcopy` where 'copied' objects are different (from an `id()` aspect) but they have similar contents.

Either way, **it ain't even hard**.

For the first case, we use a simple assignment statement, given a simple class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

And two instances of it:

```
p1 = Person("Name1", "Age1")
p2 = Person("Name2", "age2")
```

Having a new "empty" object `p3 = None`, we can copy another objects reference to it via the assignment operator:

```
p3 = p1  # p1 and p3 point to the same Person Instance

print(p3.name)  # 'Name1'
print(p3 is p1)  # True, same object

# Changes we make to a copy are visible to other copies.
p3.name = "Change name"  
p1.name   # 'Change name'
```

To make a **[`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)** of an object, meaning *identical from a content aspect*  we can use **[`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)**:

```
from copy import deepcopy

# copy contents of p3
p4 = copy.deepcopy(p3) 

print(p4.name) # prints "Change name"

# changes now are insulated to p4.
p4.name = " Another name"
print(p3.name)  # print 'Change name'
```